# group_contact usando left join mysql e separador

Tags: mysql, query

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou com uma dúvida como montar uma query usando group_concat.

Tenho 2 tabelas:

```
Prova
ID     Name        Respostas_ID      Status
1      Teste 1     1,2               1
2      Teste 2     2,4,5             1
3      Teste 3     4,5               0
```

Na segunda tabela tenho:

```
Respostas
ID      Name
1       Resposta A
2       Resposta B
3       Resposta C
4       Resposta D
5       Resposta E
```

Através da **Tabela A** faço uma vinculação dos anúncios existente na **Tabela B**

Estou montando  seguinte query:

```
SELECT
    prova.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `respostas`.`name` SEPARATOR ',' )
FROM
    LEFT JOIN respostas ON prova.respostas_id = respostas.id
WHERE
    prova.`status` = 1 
GROUP BY
    prova.id
```

Ao fazer essa consulta ele somente me traz o primeiro valor da tabela:

```
ID      Name        Respostas
1       Teste 1     Resposta A
2       Teste 2     Resposta B
```

Mas eu precisaria que ele me retornasse da seguinte forma:

```
ID      Name        Respostas
1       Teste 1     Resposta A,Resposta B
2       Teste 2     Resposta B,Resposta D,Resposta E
```

Para esse resultado estou montando em um view do MYSQL para não precisar trazer resultados que estão desativados. A ideia disso é ter uma otimização melhor do banco.

Se alguém consegui me ajudar ou tiver uma melhor sugestão de como fazer fico agradecido.

Abraços

Comment: Seu campo Respostas_ID é multivalorado?

Comment: O que seria multivalorado? Se for o que imagino é sim, ele recebe as respostas de cada pergunta e armazena na tabela de prova. @anonimo

Comment: Neste caso não é possível utilizar o JOIN pois os campos especificados na cláusula ON serão diferentes. Talvez seja possível se você fizer uma grande ginástica pesquisando por substrings do campo.

Comment: Entendi,  vou tentar pensar em uma melhor forma de fazer isso

Comment: Consegui resolver isso usando uma função do MySQL chamada FIND_IN_SET. Vou posta como eu fiz. @anonimo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi a questão usando a função FIND_IN_SET do MySQL

O resultado da consulta ficou assim:

```
SELECT
    prova.id,
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `respostas`.`name` SEPARATOR ',' )
FROM
    LEFT JOIN respostas ON FIND_IN_SET(respostas.id, prova.respostas_id)
WHERE
    prova.`status` = 1 
GROUP BY
    prova.id
```